# separate sequence of job from implementation with design pattern

Tags: java, oop

I have a scenario where one method have to be called before another one. Actually sort of processing item in sequence(order). I want to separate implementation of process from calling them in sequence. To do so, are there any design pattern?

Think like;

```
  in file x                     

      call algorithm1
      call algorithm2
      ...
      call algorithmN
```

And, each algorithmX have its own class and file.

Comment: Yes, there is, a Command Pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern

Answer (score 0):

### [Facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern)

Provide a unified interface to a set of interfaces in a subsystem. Façade defines a higher-level interface that makes the subsystem easier to use.

---

It's better explained by [GofPatterns](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/Facade.aspx)

The facade pattern is ideal when working with a large number of interdependent classes, or with classes that require the use of multiple methods, particularly when they are complicated to use or difficult to understand.

The facade class is a "wrapper" that contains a set of members that are easily understood and simple to use. These members access the subsystem on behalf of the facade user, hiding the implementation details.

---

Example: Home theater system

Look at `WatchMovie` method that **performs a set the operations in sequence**.

```
WatchMovie(){
    TV.on()
    AC.start()
    Light.dim()
    DVDPlayer.start()
}
```

Here is pictorial representation:

[image]